# A little clarification about 呼んでくる

Tags: grammar

1)What is the meaning of the てくる form in this specific case?(I more or less know the meanings of てくる but I can't tell which one is used in 呼んでくる)

2)Does it imply going somewhere or this action can be done by telephone staying at the same place?

3)If the person goes somewhere to accomplish this action, does he need to come back with the target person or this verb only says that the target person will be called by the doer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible duplicate of

> [Some questions regarding ~てくる (edited)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18637/some-questions-regarding-%e3%81%a6%e3%81%8f%e3%82%8b-edited)
>
> [Understanding てくる in these sentences](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/55192/understanding-%e3%81%a6%e3%81%8f%e3%82%8b-in-these-sentences)
>
> [Verbs +「~てくる」 , which verbs?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3160/verbs-%e3%81%a6%e3%81%8f%e3%82%8b-which-verbs)
>
> [Difference between -ていく and -てくる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/676/difference-between-%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%81%8f-and-%e3%81%a6%e3%81%8f%e3%82%8b)
>
> [Meaning of くる in 鼻の奥まで染みこんでくる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33624/meaning-of-%e3%81%8f%e3%82%8b-in-%e9%bc%bb%e3%81%ae%e5%a5%a5%e3%81%be%e3%81%a7%e6%9f%93%e3%81%bf%e3%81%93%e3%82%93%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8f%e3%82%8b/33631#33631)

(though some of these are much more in-depth than is needed to answer your question)

**1)** Simply put, **呼んでくる** (in the sense of calling someone over, by whatever means) would be translated as

> "I'll come back after calling (them)."

or

> "I'll go call (them) and come back."

**2)** In this sense, the implication of this phrase is that the act of calling will take place elsewhere, after which the speaker will return to this place, or to person to whom they are speaking.

**3)** Also in this sense, the use of **てくる** here is essentially a statement of intention to return to the current location, so it would be strange if the speaker chose not to come back.

**As @CSPP noted in the comments, there is another possible meaning of 呼んでくる, which can be thought of as "to come to call (someone) (a certain name)" ... the "come" represented by this てくる does not represent movement, but rather a change over time, or a choice to do something, in this case, call someone by a certain name.**

> **私{わたし}を親分{おやぶん}と呼{よ}んでくる連中{れんちゅう}　—　Those who (come to) call me "boss"**

in this case, there is no physical movement being implied, instead the  てくる form here represents a "psychological" change, in the sense that the action is being applied "toward" the subject in some emotional or mental sense.

Comment: Incomplete answer. 呼んでくる also means "come up calling..." in sentences such as わたしをママって呼んでくるおねえさん or 名字で呼んでくる男友達にイラっとする. In the case you describe, the て form only implies a succession of two actions (call and come), but in the case I describe, the て form implies a superposition of actions (come by calling) IMO

Comment: hmm. I see. simply put, that second  て form would in English be translated as "calls X Y" as in "calls me Mom" or "calls me by my last name"... hmm.

Comment: Yes, but for the sake of understanding I think it's better to interprete (=understand) it as "come calling" since the nuance of くる isn't implied in the English  "calls X Y"

Comment: can I ask though, is that sense of "coming" really important in the Japanese? What I mean is, if someone uses  呼んでくる in that sense, are they specifically trying to denote that the calling always happens as the other person is coming along, or is that information kind of "incidental"?

Comment: I will edit my answer to include this second meaning, with credit to you, if that is acceptable.

Comment: In this case "くる" doesn't really mean "come" as in "physically move towards someone" but rather mean something like "come up calling me" or even "start calling me", and I think it's really different from 呼ぶ because 呼ぶ only means "call" without any nuance. If you used 呼ぶ in the two sentences I quoted, the nuance would really be different and without a pronoun, we wouldn't know whether the 呼んで is about calling yourself or someone else.

Comment: @eric さん、 The ～てくる that CSPP is talking about is ... 「電話をかけてくる」 https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/29520/9831 , 「話しかけてくる」 https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/33631/9831

Comment: .... hmm. The sense of "psychologically moving toward someone"... This sense is not spoken of so directly in English, so I must be kind of internalizing or maybe "skipping over" this implied meaning when I hear てくる used in this way... thank you @Chocolate I will try to address this...

Comment: I removed my -1, thanks for editing!